# Create Specific 365 Day Years to Compare Data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, plotly, line-plot

I have what seems like it should be a trivial exercise but I can't seem to crack it. I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
size = 1000
d = {'Farmer':np.random.choice( ['Bob','Suyzn','John'], size),
        'Commodity': np.random.choice( ['Corn','Wheat','Soy'], size),
        'Date':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2018','12/12/2022', freq='D'), size),
        'Bushels': np.random.randint(20,100, size=(size))
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I use pandas to look at the different farmers & the amount of the different commodities they deliver. I want the ability to look at custom years where I can provide the start_month & start_day to create a new column called 'Interval' that shows the data based on what I choose. This is the function that works for that:

```
def calculate_intervals(df, start_month, start_day):
    """Adds column called Interval to df. It 

    Args:
        df (dataframe): Dataframe to pass that's been filtered to what you want.
        start_month (int): Month to start.
        start_day (int): Day to start.

    Returns:
        dataframe: Dataframe with 'Interval' added
    """    
    # Filter the DataFrame
    filtered_df = df
    filtered_df['Year'] = filtered_df['Date'].dt.year
    
    # Define the date ranges for each interval
    intervals = []
    for year in filtered_df['Year'].unique():
        start_date = pd.to_datetime(f"{year}-{start_month}-{start_day}")
        end_date = pd.to_datetime(f"{year+1}-{start_month}-{start_day}") - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
        intervals.append((start_date, end_date))
    
    # Create a function to assign the interval label to each row
    def assign_interval(row):
        for c, (start_date, end_date) in enumerate(intervals):
            if start_date <= row['Date'] <= end_date:
                return f"{start_date.date()} - {end_date.date()}"
        return None  # Return None if the row's date is not within any interval
    
    # Apply the interval assignment function to each row
    filtered_df['Interval'] = filtered_df.apply(assign_interval, axis=1)
    
    return filtered_df

calculate_intervals(df, start_month=7, start_day=6)
```

My goal is to take it one step further. I want to create a graph that takes the start_month & start_day & uses that as position 0 on the y-axis. The x-axis would show the next 365 days all the way out to the end. In this example, the x-axis would start at July 6 & go through July 5th of the following year. The y-axis would be the cumulative sum of bushels sold starting on July 6 through July 5th of the next year. Each custom year would be it's own line on the graph.

I have done similar exercises to graph cumulative sum starting on Jan 1 - Dec 31 of the same year, but can't figure out how to do it with a custom start date. My goal is to get a graph that looks something like this:
[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: connected with what @itprorh66 said - the steps could be 1. find the next 365 day's worth of data, 2. find the cumulative sum for each of those years, 3. plot one of those years, 4. plot the rest

Comment: to get things grouped and in a good state to plot, you could do `d = df[(df['Date'] > '1/1/2020') & (df['Date'] < '1/1/2021')][['Date','Bushels']].groupby('Date').sum().cumsum()`, then try using matplotlib with d

Comment: July 6 is not week 4 of the year. For this year, it falls into week 27.

Comment: thank you @itprorh66. I thought it was pretty specific - I want to create a graph showing July 6th as day 1 & July 5th of the next year as day 365. I am struggling to get that logic so asked here.

Comment: @CodeDifferent apologies, was just showing a drawing of what I wanted it to look like. Doesn't matter to me if it's starting on July 6 or Feb 1.

Comment: @OCa good point - I will amend.

Comment: @itprorh66 i would respectfully disagree – this is a pretty specific question that i would summarize as "how to plot cumulative values versus weeks of the year for time series data across different years". i found this useful as this is very similar to a problem i've encountered at my current job, and I think other people will benefit from this question remaining open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing would be to order your DataFrame by `Interval` and `Date`, then calculate the cumulative units sold using `groupby` and `cumsum`.

However, the main challenge is that in your desired plot, the tickmarks on the axes are cyclical, and cyclical xaxis coordinates aren't easily interpreted by Plotly. In the sample data you've provided, we want the axis to start at week 26, then loop back around to week 0 after week 52. If we convert the format of the tickmarks to strings, we may end up with multiple tickmarks with the same string for a particular week, and this will cause problems.

The best solution I could come up with is create a new column in your data that "adjusts" the day of the year by mapping it from cyclical days of the year to linear days of the year.

For example, if you begin your cumulative counts of units sold on day `187` of the year, then the x values of your plot in terms of the day of the year would look like `[187, 188, 189, ... 365, 0, 1, 2, ... 186]`, and we want to map this to `[0, 1, 2, ... 365-187, 365-187+0, 365-187+1, ... 186]`.

Then if we plot cumulative units sold against adjusted day of the year, we will get a monotonically increasing plot as desired – the only issue is that the tickmarks are in days, and that they don't reflect the actual day of the year.

[image]

To get around this, we use plotly's `ticktext` argument that allows you to overlay text for certain tickmarks, and since you want a tickmark for every 4 weeks, we can use floor division to convert the actual days of the year `[187, 188, 189, ... 365, 0, 1, 2, ... 186, 187]` to actual weeks of the year `[26, 26, ... 52, 52, 0, 0, ... 26, 26]`, and then
use a list comprehension to convert that to an array that contains empty strings except for every 28 values (4 weeks).

[image]

```
df_intervals = calculate_intervals(df, start_month=7, start_day=6)
df_intervals = df_intervals.sort_values(by=['Interval','Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
df_intervals['Cumulative_Units_Sold'] = df_intervals.groupby('Interval')['Bushels'].cumsum()

df_intervals['Day'] = df_intervals['Date'].dt.dayofyear

## the starting date for each interval is slightly different in your sample data
## because you chose dates randomly, some intervals have a start date on exactly 07-06
## while other intervals have a start date on another nearby date such as 07-07
## to mitigate this, i will take the week of the year that is most common among all intervals
day_of_year_start = df_intervals.groupby('Interval').first()['Day'].min()

df_intervals['Adjusted_Day'] = df_intervals['Day'].apply(
    lambda x: x-day_of_year_start if x>=day_of_year_start else 365+x-day_of_year_start
)

fig = px.line(
    df_intervals,
    x='Adjusted_Day',
    y='Cumulative_Units_Sold',
    color='Interval'
)

adjusted_day_of_year = np.arange(0,365+1)

actual_day_of_year = np.concatenate([np.arange(day_of_year_start, 365+1),np.arange(0,day_of_year_start)])
actual_week_of_year = actual_day_of_year // 7
# week_zero_location = np.where(actual_week_of_year == 0)[0][0] % 28

# ## i % 28 ensures we only place a tick once every 4 weeks
tick_week = [w if i % 28 == 0 else '' for i,w in enumerate(actual_week_of_year)]

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickmode='array', 
        tickvals=adjusted_day_of_year,
        ticktext=tick_week,
        title='Week of the Year'
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Units Sold'
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: I finally got a chance to check this out - this is great!! Thank you so much for taking the time to put it together. It works as I hoped it would - thank you so much!

Comment: no problem – glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

I create an "adjusted year" (`_y`) for each year start. Sadly I have to use `apply` to construct it because the `pd.Timestamp` constructor is not vectorised.

This then allows me to construct a `_dt` column which actually contains `Timedelta` objects, which index the days since inception for that adjusted year.

```
# split into groups
START_DAY, START_MONTH = 23, 8
df['_y'] = np.where(
    df['Date'] < df['Date'].dt.year.apply(
        lambda y: pd.Timestamp(y, START_MONTH, START_DAY)),
    df['Date'].dt.year - 1,
    df['Date'].dt.year)

df['_dt'] = df['Date'] - df['_y'].apply(
    lambda y: pd.Timestamp(y, START_MONTH, START_DAY))
grouped = df.groupby(['Commodity', '_y', '_dt'])['Bushels'] \
    .sum().groupby(level=[0, 1]) \
    .cumsum()
```

Through some somewhat group by operations I sum up all production occurring at each date noted. I then make the whole data set (within each commodity and adjusted year group) cumulative.

Displaying the data is more involved. I have to resample the data to 7-day intervals after the inception date. This creates, however, due to the structure of your data, a data frame with a lot of holes in it. (They are caused by the random choice creating 1 commodity record at each time.)

I therefore interpolate linearly where the data are available, which creates the nice semi-continuous lines you can see in the chart below. For further nice-display reasons, I cast the index of the `plot_data` into days and provide labels.

```
# plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, a = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
plot_data = grouped.unstack(level=1).reset_index() \
    .groupby('Commodity').resample(on='_dt', rule='7D').mean() \
    .groupby('Commodity').apply(lambda _d: _d.interpolate(limit_area='inside')) \
    .loc['Corn']
plot_data.index = plot_data.index.days
plot_data.plot(ax=a)

a.set_xlabel('Days since start')
a.set_ylabel('Bushels')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100pc sure that response engages with what the code does. The day 21 August 2023 is assigned to adjusted year 2022: the days are aligned regardless of year.

Comment: And yes further adjustment can be done to convert the `timedelta`s into real dates into year week numbers (`s.dt.weekofyear`). I avoided that because the function in the OP takes an arbitrary day input and not a week number.

Comment: oh i misread the chart so my original comment isn't correct. i guess the only other thing is that it looks like OP wants week of the year (or day of the year) to wrap around though that's a matter of adjusting the tick mark labels and doesn't change the visualization itself

Comment: @ifly6 thank you for taking the time to put this together! I was hoping the '0' on the y-axis would be the date passed in - in this case Aug 23.